# mongoose cannot connect when replica set is enabled

Tags: node.js, docker, mongoose

I am attempting to dockerize a nodeJs application, however I cannot connect using mongoose, Mongodb Compass works (from host OS)

The app connects to a Mongodb server ( also on docker) using the following code:

```
const mongoUri: string = "mongodb://mongo:27017?replicaSet=rs0";
mongoose
    .connect(mongoUri)
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to database")).catch(err => console.log(err.reason));
```

I am using the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4.0
    volumes:
      - ./mongo:/etc/mongo
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    entrypoint: [/etc/mongo/start.sh]
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    hostname: mongo
  
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    build: ./sp_backend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8883:8883
      - 8884:8884
    hostname: backend
```

The start.sh is setting a custom mongod.conf as following:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
```

and in the mongod.conf the replication is set (to enable change streams)

```
...
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
...
```

I also ran rs.initiate() on the mongo instance at the first startup, and I can connect from the host to the mongo server using Mongodb Compass, however mongoose spits out the following error:

```
TopologyDescription {
  type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
  servers: Map(1) {
    '127.0.0.1:27017' => ServerDescription {
      address: '127.0.0.1:27017',
      type: 'Unknown',
      hosts: [],
      passives: [],
      arbiters: [],
      tags: {},
      minWireVersion: 0,
      maxWireVersion: 0,
      roundTripTime: -1,
      lastUpdateTime: 25342884,
      lastWriteDate: 0,
      error: [MongoNetworkError],
      topologyVersion: null,
      setName: null,
      setVersion: null,
      electionId: null,
      logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
      primary: null,
      me: null,
      '$clusterTime': null
    }
  },
  stale: false,
  compatible: true,
  heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
  localThresholdMS: 15,
  setName: 'rs0',
  maxElectionId: new ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000001"),
  maxSetVersion: 1,
  commonWireVersion: 0,
  logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
}
```

My thinking is that the servers map should not contain 127.0.0.1 as a server since the mongo runs on a sepparate server. I also checked to ping the database container from the nodejs container and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Later update:
It seems I was using the an old mongo docker image, after upgrading (mongo:4.4.0) to mongo:latest fixed the problem.